# How can I increase window title font size?

Tags: gnome-terminal, fonts, window

When monitor resolution is increased I want to increase title bar's font size as well. How can I achieve this?

Comment: When you say "monitor resolution is increased" areyou refering to HiDPI? if so, what Ubuntu release and Desktop Enviroment you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply run following command on terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences titlebar-font 'Ubuntu Bold 11'
```

Number `11` is default font size for title bar font, I believe you want to adjust their size to your preferred size.

Answer (score 1):

Install unity-tweak-tool:

```
sudo apt install unity-tweak-tool
```

After than you can adjust the fonts for the different locations in that tool

Answer (score 0):

You can also change this setting graphically using Tweaks. Install it, if you haven't already, using:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Then open Tweaks → *Fonts* → change *Legacy Window Titles* to the desired font and size.

[image]