# Window's Title Bar Text Desproportionally Big

Tags: gnome, 20.04, bug-reporting, titlebar, visual-artifacts

I recently had many visual bugs due I changed the name of my home folder's username, one of them is a bigger title bar text than usual. I've not found a way to modify this yet sadly, so I came here to ask Ubuntu how.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind, 5 more minutes of searching and I found a command in another question:
[How can I increase window title font size?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867807/how-can-i-increase-window-title-font-size) (ironically asking the oposite).
This is the command if someone has my problem in the future:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences titlebar-font 'Ubuntu Bold 11'
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked for me. But I also found out, that you use the Gnome Tweak Tool to set this.

Tweak > Fonts > Legacy Window Titles

At least I think it is the same setting because it is changing the same thing for me 