# Why do my title bars on GTK3 apps sometimes get HUGE?

Tags: gnome

Normally the title bars on all my apps look fine:

[image]

But sometimes the application title bars for some apps are HUGE:

[image]

When this happens, it is true for gvim, LibreOffice, shutter. I *think* what these have in common are that they are GTK(3?) apps (please correct me). Gnome apps are fine.

This is only sometimes. I suspect this has something to do with me using 100% scaling when using an external monitor and 200% on my laptop and something goes wrong when switching from one to another. When it has happened, a gnome logout/login cycle restores "normal" appearance.

- Is this something others have noticed?
- Can I avoid it completely somehow?
- Can I restore the old title size once it has occurred without having to reboot or logout/login?

Comment: Well, both are GTK3 apps. The "Gnome apps" are using CSD (client side decoration) instead of a metacity Window decorator - which is the fallback.  Try to [change the Window title font](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867807/how-can-i-increase-window-title-font-size)